# python-docx - How do I add an image at a specific position?

Tags: python, image, position, element, docx

I have a pre-existing document that I need to add a picture to. The picture needs to be inside a frame in the upper right corner of the document. The frame it needs to go in is already part of the document. All I need to do as far as I understand is add a run to the paragraph inside the frame (which is a v:shape element) and then add a picture to that and the position of the picture should assume the position of the surrounding element. The only issue is I can only get a paragraph, run or picture to get added to the end of the document but  not to a specific element farther down the document. Also I whereas I can set a size to the image there is no option to set the position of it on the page. Is there anyway to do this? Again what I'm wanting to do is add a picture to a document at a specific x, y position on the page.

edit:
Here's my latest attempt. I don't know any other way than to drill down deep into the document to get the element I want to add a picture to:

```
for r in doc.paragraphs[0].runs:
    for r2 in r._r.iterchildren():
        if r2.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}pict':
            for r3 in r2.iterchildren():
                if r3.tag == '{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml}shape':
                    for r4 in r3.iterchildren():
                        if r4.tag == '{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml}textbox':
                            for r5 in r4.iterchildren():
                                if r5.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}txbxContent':
                                    for r6 in r5.iterchildren():
                                        if r6.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}p':
                                            #pic = doc.add_picture('image.jpg', width=1508760, height=1905000)
                                            #pic_xml = pic._inline.xml
                                            #r6.append(pic._inline)
                                            pr = r6.add_run()
                                            pr.add_picture('image.jpg', width=1508760, height=1905000)
```

I've read examples that say to add a run to a paragraph and then add a picture to that run. This is what I'm trying but all I get is an error like this: "'CT_P' object has no attribute 'add_run'"

The fact is though is that you actually can add a run to a paragraph but this is saying that the element I'm drilling down to is a different object type than a regular paragraph object. Does that make sense? Do I have to covert this element somehow?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: I added my code above.